# replacing tires and tubes

Tags: repair

I own a trek 7000 hybrid and was wondering if there are aftermarket parts i.e. inner tubes and tires that will work for it. the wheels, tubes and tires are all bontrager if this helps any suggestions?

Comment: See these questions about [tire sizing](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/9238/how-are-tire-sizes-measured) and [tube sizes](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6839/where-is-the-proper-location-to-measure-the-tube-size)

Comment: Look on the side of the tire for something like "700x35c" or "26/1.25" -- this is the tire size.  Brand doesn't matter (other than for quality).

Answer (score 2):

You just need to match the size.  Bontrager is just a tire that Trek used for that bike.

The size will be on the tire
The bike comes with a 700x35c
The 700 is the rim size - you have to get a tire that size
The 35 is the width of tire - you have some variance there
For your bike might as well just stay with a 700x35c
For a tube you will get a range like 700 x (32 - 45)

Comment: Well, 700c is the rim size. There are technically 700a,700b rims but they're exceedingly rare.